# Multiple tables on one page with prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, prawn

I'm using prawn for pdf generation and everything works quite well, but now I'm having a bit of a problem.
When I put multiple tables on one page, they just get put over each other and not under each other. 
Is this normal behaviour and what can I do about it?

I add the tables on the most normal behaviour btw :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What is the code you're using to create the PDF document with Prawn?

Without that, I'm guessing that you need to use 'bounding boxes' to seperate the different sections / tables in your document. Each bounding box is an area for content rendering, and new bounding boxes or text is rendered below that. See [bounding_box() documentation](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/prawn-core/classes/Prawn/Document.html#M000116) or the example below:

```
> pdf.bounding_box([100,500], :width => 100, :height => 300) do
>   pdf.text "This text will flow in a very narrow box starting" +
>     "from [100,500]. The pointer will then be moved to [100,200]" +
>     "and return to the margin_box"
> end
```